# Disabling weekends in KendoUI Angular datepicker

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-ui-angular2

Is there any simple way to disable weekends (sat, sun) in KendoUI Angular datepicker?

Comment: Show what you try  ?

Comment: You should look into creating your own template for each cell and providing a function to check if it should be disabled. If you'll got stuck at some point, paste what you'll have into new question or edit current one and we will try to help you. See this link: https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dateinputs/datepicker/templates/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the Angular version, but in the jQuery version there is an [option](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/editors/datepicker/overview#disable-dates) for that.

HTH